# How to identify errors when loading data into BigQuery

Tags: bigdata, google-bigquery

While importing a ~5 GB file with ~41 million rows into BigQuery, I received the following error message:

```
Errors:
File: 0 / Offset:4026531933 / Line:604836 / Field:39, Value cannot be converted to expected type.
```

My question: how would I use the Offset / Line information in the error message above to determine the line number of the offending record?

Answer (score 3):

For large files, BigQuery splits them up into large pieces and loads them in parallel. That means BigQuery doesn't know how many lines come before a particular piece, since the file was chunked by byte ranges. The offset mentioned is the start of the chunk from the beginning of the file, in bytes. So the error should come at 604836 lines after the 4026531933th byte.

You can isolate the line with the bad value on Unix with:

```
tail -c +4026531933 <input file> | head -n $((604836 + 1)) | tail -1
```

Or with sed:

tail -c +  | sed -n $(( + 1))p